# Handle Ethernet interrupt in DOS

Tags: c, x86, dos, interrupt

Is there such thing as Ethernet interrupt in C under DOS for incoming data?
I have written an application that waits for incoming data in my "while(True)" loop and it works perfectly. But I want to know if there is an interrupt service which can handle incoming data outside of my while(true) loop.

Comment: Yes, of course there is code to handle the ethernet interrupt. You should really describe what you are trying to accomplish. Are you really using DOS? (There hasn't been a release of DOS for about 20 years).

Comment: Yes, I am really using DOS. I am working with a pc/104 , vdx-6354 to be more specific and that's based on vortex86dx processor.
I have an application which controls several motors. It's written with Turbo C. At the user end, there is a GUI written in C# which communicates with the main application via serial. Now, for some reason, we need to replace serial with Ethernet.
In serial based version, whenever data is received via serial, an interrupt in called but I have not found any solution for Ethernet incoming data interrupt.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping you meant DOS as in "the windows command line". I used to do that kind of stuff 20 years ago. Now I just use Linux because it's much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Having had a wander through [RBIL](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ralf/files.html) it would seem that doing interrupt level ethernet is out of the question. Ethernet is very much in the TCP/IP arena. To that end therefore I suggest fighting very hard to stay on serial interfaces, or else start studying [TCP/IP network for MS-DOS](http://users.telenet.be/mydotcom/library/network/dostcpip.htm) and [DOS TCP/IP Networking with Packet Drivers](http://brutman.com/Dos_Networking/).